# Find TextViews in xml without fontFamily attribute using regex

Tags: android, regex, xml

This is sample input string for test

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_refer_invite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_refer_earn"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ms500"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
        android:paddingLeft="16.7dp"
        android:paddingRight="16.7dp"
        android:text="@{data.description}"
        android:textColor="@color/color_858585"
        android:textSize="13.3sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_refer_code"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_refer_invite"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ms500"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_refer_code"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{data==null?``:`Invite code : `+data.referralCode}"
        android:textColor="#9c9c9c"
        android:textSize="14.3sp"/>
```

I want to find out every Textview without `android:fontFamily` using regex, I am not sure how to apply negative lookup properly. The regex i am using online Regex tester is

`<TextView[\s\S]*?(?!fontFamily)[\s\S]*?>`

But it return every textview (matches all textviews)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<TextView[\s\S]*?(?!fontFamily)[\s\S]*?>` pattern matches `<TextView`, then any 0+ chars, as few as possible (thus, skipping at first), then asserts that there is no `fontFamily` substring immediately to the right of the current location, and then matches any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first `>` (thus, the last `[\s\S]*?` is expanded all the way long to the end of match). The lookahead does not play any specific role (unless `fontFamily` goes right after `<TextView` which is never the case).

You need a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) here if you want to use a regex for a one-off task like this:

```
<TextView(?:(?!fontFamily)[^>])*>
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:(?!fontFamily)[^>])*` part will match any char but `>` that does not start a `fontFamily` substring, as many as possible occurrences, up to a `>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EkV0S/1).

You may unwrap the token using negated character classes to make it more efficient:

```
<TextView[^f>]*(?:f(?!ontFamily)[^f>]*)*>
         *******************************
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EkV0S/2).